# How to convert List<Object> to POJO using JPA native Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How to convert List of object to josn (key,value) format?

I am having one class with name `ClientRT` and in that class four fields are there i.e.

```
res_nclient_room_type_id, res_sclient_rt_desc,res_sclient_rt_name, res_sclient_rt_code
```

**Service class**

```
public List<Object> callSP() throws IOException {   

        List<Object> crt=crtRepo.roomtype(60);          

        //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

        //String rtobject= mapper.writeValueAsString(crt);

        return crt;
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRoomTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientRoomType, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select * from roomtype(:int_inst_id)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> roomtype(@Param("int_inst_id")Integer int_inst_id);
}
```

**List of Object**

```
 [
      [
        1,
        "TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED",
        "TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED",
        "000"
      ],
      [
        2,
        "FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM",
        "FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM",
        "050"
      ],
```

How to convert In this format

```
[
 {
    "res_nclient_room_type_id":1 , 
    "res_sclient_rt_desc": "TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED", 
    "res_sclient_rt_name":"TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED" , 
    "res_sclient_rt_code":"000" 

 },
 {
  "res_nclient_room_type_id":2 , 
  "res_sclient_rt_desc": "FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM", 
  "res_sclient_rt_name":"FACILITIES - AVAILABLE ROOM" , 
  "res_sclient_rt_code":"050" 
 },
]
```

Can any one suggest me how I can do that?

Comment: honestly show the code that you have or tried

Comment: I added what I tried

Comment: One question to ask is why you get a `List<Object>` rather than a `List` of appropriate room types.

Comment: if I am using List `<ClientRT>` then I am getting This Error : `No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.spacestudy.model.ClientRT]" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem is with `JPA` use projection for doing that, create one interface with fields [Interface-based Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces)

```
interface ClientRT {

  Long getResNclientRoomTypeId();
  String getResSclientRtDesc();
  String getResSclientRtName();
  String getResSclientRtCode();
  }
```

**Query**

```
 @Query(value = "select * from roomtype(:int_inst_id)", nativeQuery = true)
List<ClientRT> roomtype(@Param("int_inst_id")Integer int_inst_id);
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot. its working from two days I was trying this